# SQL Loop through table A & Insert/ Update in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, foreach, cursor

What would be the best way in a stored proc to loop through all the rows of table "A" & Check by Id if record exists in table "B" & depending upon result (found in table B or not) perform a "Insert" or "Update" into table "B".

For example:

```
//LOOP START
    //if ID Exists in Table B.
        //Take current row table a values and update table "B"
    Else
        //Take current row table a values and insert into table "B"
//LOOP END
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Learn to forget  *looping* in favor of set operations as much as possible. Loops are inherently slow, and DBMS engines are optimized to work with sets. Loops (AKA cursor operations) should be the last resort when there's absolutely no way to perform a set operation.

Comment: Thank you Ken White, for explaining it in such simple terms. Appreciate your effort. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MERGE INTO command on SQL 2008

```
MERGE INTO table_B as Target
USING (
    Select
        Id, Field1, Field2
    FROM table_A ) as Source
ON Source.Id = Target.Id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT( Id, Field1, Field2 )
    VALUES( Source.Id, Source.Field1, Source.Field2 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET
        target.Id = Source.Id
        ,target.Field1 = Source.Field1
        ,target.Field2 = Source.Field2
;
```

Comment: Thank you J Greene, this works like a charm. Marked as answer.